# Polygon simplification without intersection in GeoPandas/Shapely

Tags: geopandas, shapely, python-3, generalization

Is there an in-the-can solution for simplifying a boundary that won't intersect the original poly?

Something like .convex_hull but with a fillet option possibly?

For example, .simplify() produces variations (depending on the arg magnitude) of this:

[image]

and .exterior just gives me the outline.

If I buffer then simplify the buffer (purple, below), I get something that is satisfactory:

[image]

But not exactly what I'm looking for and only after iterating buffer and simplification args and multiple manual inspections.

While I could write a test for intersection and incrementally iterate buff and/or simplification args until it passes, I figured I'd check if there was already something out there.

Comment: Perhaps a con*cave* hull? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378168/737471 https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/

Answer (score 1):

GEOS recently added [PolygonHullSimplify](http://libgeos.org/doxygen/3.11/geos__c_8h.html#a8545b2a279924742f98324c484697426), which constructs inner and outer hulls of polygons using a simplification tolerance.  See this [blog post](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2022/04/outer-and-inner-concave-polygon-hulls.html) for details.

[image]

Unfortunately this isn't yet exposed in Shapely.  Perhaps opening an issue would motivate this to happen.

Comment: Looks like that would do the trick.  Cheers for the heads-up